# Paging number list alignment in datatable

Tags: html, css, datatables

I am having problems aligning paging numbers in datatables, below is the code.

Datatables library is used to dynamicaly generate a table which includes a paginate and search functionality. I customized the paginate numbering with CSS however the alignment seem to be off the grid.

```
.dataTables_paginate a {
    color: black;
    float: left;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background-color .3s;
}

.dataTables_paginate a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

.dataTables_paginate a:hover:not(.active) {background-color: #ddd;}
```

[image: Paging]

The paging is not aligning to the grid.

> Datatable EJS

```
<h2><% var projectlist = JSON.parse(data); %></h2>
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">CSI ID</th>
      <th scope="col">App Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <!-- get projects array from the data property -->
<% var counter = 0; %>
<% var evale = 'CSI:'; %>

<% for (var key in projectlist) { %>

  <% if (projectlist.hasOwnProperty(key)) { %>
    <% var csiid = projectlist[key].name.substring(projectlist[key].name.lastIndexOf(":")+1,projectlist[key].name.lastIndexOf("]")); %>
    <% if (projectlist[key].name.match(evale)) { %>
    <% counter = counter + 1; %>
    <tr>
    <td><%= counter %></td>
    <td><%= csiid %></td>
    <td><%= projectlist[key].name.replace(/\[.*?\]\s?/g, '') %></td>
     <td>TESTED</td>
    </tr>
  <% } %>
  <% } %>
   <% } %>


  </tbody>
</table>
```

Paginate runtime HTML generated by datatables.js

```
<div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="example_paginate">
    <a class="paginate_button previous disabled" aria-controls="example" data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="0" id="example_previous">Previous</a>
    <span>
        <a class="paginate_button current" aria-controls="example" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0">1</a>
        <a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="example" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0">2</a>
        <a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="example" data-dt-idx="3" tabindex="0">3</a>
        <a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="example" data-dt-idx="4" tabindex="0">4</a>
        <a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="example" data-dt-idx="5" tabindex="0">5</a>
        <span class="ellipsis">…</span>
        <a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="example" data-dt-idx="6" tabindex="0">33</a>
    </span>
    <a class="paginate_button next" aria-controls="example" data-dt-idx="7" tabindex="0" id="example_next">Next</a>
</div>
```

Comment: show me your HTML

Comment: Can you check in the browser's Inspector if your styles are being used and not overridden by other styles? The paging elements are ofter declared with a CSS selector `.pagination>li>a` instead of `.dataTables_paginate a` ?

Comment: Can you provide an online test/demo we can check?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can easily do that by using the below css:

```
.dataTables_paginate{
display:flex;
align-items:center;
}
.dataTables_paginate a{
padding:0 10px;
}
```

Display flex will wrap all elements in single row. Align Items center will position the elements vertically center.

Comment: This works but the pagination is aligned outside the the data table area, i tried changing align-items still doesn't work.

Comment: can you post snippet so that we can get better idea

Answer (score 2):

Your "clear example" works great.

[image]

So I think some of needed styles was declarated somewhere with higher priority.

If it's not possible to remove other declaration, add **`!important`** to `float`. And add `display` to be sure.

```
...
.dataTables_paginate a {
    color: black;
    display: block !important;
    float: left !important;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background-color .3s;
 }
 ...
```

Of course it'll work only if your CSS has connected.

Comment: I would suggest against using `!important` as it makes maintaining the code harder and rather find out why the styles are overridden.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.dataTables_paginate a {
    color: black;
    float: left;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background-color .3s;
}

.dataTables_paginate a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

.dataTables_paginate a:hover:not(.active) {background-color: #ddd;}
```

```html
<div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="example_paginate">
    <a class="paginate_button previous disabled" aria-controls="example" data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="0" id="example_previous">Previous</a>
    <span>
        <a class="paginate_button current" aria-controls="example" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0">1</a>
        <a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="example" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0">2</a>
        <a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="example" data-dt-idx="3" tabindex="0">3</a>
        <a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="example" data-dt-idx="4" tabindex="0">4</a>
        <a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="example" data-dt-idx="5" tabindex="0">5</a>
        <span class="ellipsis">…</span>
        <a class="paginate_button " aria-controls="example" data-dt-idx="6" tabindex="0">33</a>
    </span>
    <a class="paginate_button next" aria-controls="example" data-dt-idx="7" tabindex="0" id="example_next">Next</a>
</div>
```

This is yours. I works perfectly. Check in html file and make sure that you link to css file correctly. Maybe you indicate wrong path to css file.